# Where is JAXB binding in Netbeans module

Tags: xml, netbeans, module, jaxb

I want to create Java classes from an XSD file. I was able to do this in a Netbeans project. When I select New file -> Other -> XML there is an option for creating a JAX Binding.

I am porting a swing application to the Netbeans Platform, and so am moving code to modules. But now when I select the above in the module the JAXB Binding file type option does not appear under the XML category for creating new file. I do have the JAXB Wizard module dependency installed.

How do I enable the JAXB Binding file type option?

Answer (score 1):

NetBeans module projects do not support the JAXB wizard. One of the reasons is that module projects don't support generated sources. See [bug 135224](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=135224) for more information.

A workaround is to create a normal Java Class Library project containing the JAXB binding. Then create a Library Wrapper Module project that wraps the output jar of the Java Class Library and makes it available to the NetBeans Platform.

A downside to this approach is keeping the two projects in sync. Each time you update the Java Class Library containing the JAXB binding, you must remember to copy the new jar to the Wrapper Module. The [Developer's FAQ](http://deadlock.netbeans.org/hudson/job/faqsuck/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/other/faqsuck/build/faq.html#DevFaqWrapperModules) has some advice for manually adding build dependencies to automate this.